# How to print certain # of times based on input

Tags: python

I wan't to make a program which will print an input a certain number of times based on another input.

```
msg = input ("What is your message?")
times = input ("How many times do you wan't your message repeated?")
for times in range(6):
    print(msg)
```

Comment: Your forloop is wrong, you want `for i in range(int(times)):`

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You have to use raw_input() if you want to enter strings. There is also an error in your range-operator. Use it like this:

```
msg = raw_input('What is your message?')
times = raw_input("How many times do you wan't your message repeated?")
for i in range(int(times)):
    print(msg)
```

Output:

```
What is your message? Hello World.
How many times do you wan't your message repeated?3
 Hello World.
 Hello World.
 Hello World.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: It would be better security-wise to use `raw_input` and convert to `int`, as `input` will execute whatever you enter. Also, you can simply use `range(times)` (after converting `range` to `int`).

Comment: I meant to say after converting `times` to `int`. (Can't edit my comment above)

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate on a range of numbers between 0 and `times`, however you also need to convert `times` to an integer.

In order to do that your `for` loop needs to be `for i in range(int(times)):`